# Calling thread.interrupt on a class in between io operations (is this a race condition)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My question is specific to android, but I suspect is applies to Java threads in general.

Let's say the run loop of a worker thread is doing this.  Reading bytes from a network stream and doing stuff with each chunk read.

```
 class MyWorker implements Runnable {

     boolean _exitFlag;
     Thread _thread;


     void run()
     {
         HttpUrlConnection connection;

         // connection establishment not shown for brevity

         while(_exitFlag == false)
         {
              InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
              int result;
              try
              {
                  result = stream.read(bytearray);
                  if (result == -1)
                      break;
                  processBytes(bytearray, result); 
              }
              catch(IOException ioex)
              {
                  break;                  
              }
         }
     }
```

Now the other thread is ready to signal this thread to exit by calling another method on this class:

```
public void stop()
{
    _exitFlag = true;
    _thread.interrupt();
    _thread.join();
}
```

It's my understanding that the `_thread.interrupt` call will wake up the blocking io operation on the `stream.read` call with an exception derived from IOException.  That's assuming the thread is actually at that point in the code.

Let's say the `stop` call was made immediately after the worker thread checked the `_exitFlag==false` condition but before it got to the subsequent `read` call?

Will the subsequent call to `stream.read()` immediately throw an exception if the thread has a posted interrupt?  Or will it continue to block and wait for the IO operation to complete? In other words, is this a race condition?

What is a good pattern for signaling a worker thread that may be in the middle of a long blocking io operation to exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are separate things. The call to Thread.interrupt only sets a flag in the target Thread. It is up to that Thread to handle the call. If the Thread is sleeping then an InterruptedException will be thrown and it is up to the target Thread to handle the exception (or throw it again). However, if the target Thread is not in a state that throws InterruptedException (not sleeping and not joining) then it is up to the target Thread to be constantly checking for the signal via `Thread.interrupted()`.

In your example, it is up to the thread reading the stream to check periodically if the `interrupted` flag has been set or not.

In your code, I would check the flag using something like

```
              result = stream.read(bytearray);
              if (result == -1)
                  break;
              processBytes(bytearray, result);
              if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                  // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
                  // handle the interruption here by throwing an Exception or returning.. or something else
               }
```

Comment: Thanks. I already knew all this. But even with the mod as you have it, there's still a potential race condition. The call to `Thread.interruped()` could return false, followed by a context switch to the other thread back that then calls `thread.interrupt`, then context switch back to the worker thread that is now entering the `read` call again.  Does `read` ultimately call Thread.isInterruped() before it blocks?  That's really the question.

Comment: True. That's why I like to add my own method 'beenInterrupted` that will check and stay checked if `interrupted` has ever been called.

Comment: That's the same thing as `_exitFlag` in my code sample. That still doesn't solve the race condition if `read` doesn't check the interrupt condition prior to blocking. I think the solution is to have the `stop` method loop on `thread.interrupt()` and only block on `thread.join` for a fraction of a second.

Comment: Yes, that will work if the Thread doesn't have any cleanup job to do.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code

```
package test;

public class BlockingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Sleeper());
        t.start();
        System.out.println("interrupting");
        t.interrupt();
        try {

            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class Sleeper implements Runnable {
        private final Object lock = new Object();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int I = 0; I < 120000; I++) {
                    System.out.println(I);
                }
                System.out.println("Stopped counting, waiting");
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   

    }

}
```

Here the thread running in Sleeper will throw an interrupted exception when it enters the monitor on the lock object. .interrupt() was called by the main thread long before it gets to that point. So calling interrupt on a thread prior to entering some blocking operation will throw an interrupted exception if the call to that threads interrupt was made prior to the blocking op. It is good to point out that a call to interrupted on Thread will clear the interruped flag, so if this happens:

```
Thread.interrupt();
....
Thread.interrupted();
Thread.interrupted();
```

The second call to Thread.interrupted() will return false.
Heres the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29

I do remember hearing long ago that its not a good idea to rely on interrupts as exit conditions. Typically I will implement an exit() method which sets some exit flag, and calls interrupt on the thread in question. This makes sure that I either evaluate the exit flag and exit, or if the thread is waiting in a loop on a monitor someplace, that it will throw an IOException, and subsequently evaluate the exit flag and exit. But I can imagine situations where you want to set a flag, but not necessarily interrupt eg. ensuring that a thread doesnt abort a write operation and say, corrupt some persisted data its writing.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that throw `InterruptedException` will check before blocking if the thread is interrupted. From the docs of `InterruptedException`:

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and the thread is interrupted, either **before** or during the activity.

(Emphasis mine)

Just try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at ...
```

This means that you can forego checking the flag yourself (which would be prone to all sorts of race conditions anyway) if you are often calling another method that throws `InterruptedException`.